# GPS elevation/altitude precision - relative position

Tags: android, ios, api, gps, geolocation

I'm trying to find a good way to track location of people in a building.  I would ultimately like to be able to create a graphic on demand showing where employees are in a building - which floor (elevation), and where on the floor they are located (lat/lon).  I have read that elevation is relative to the WGS84 ellipsoid, not sea level necessarily, which is fine.  I can define a baseline of where the first floor is, for example, and then calculate the difference of a person's current location from there.  If I understand correctly, the general precision lat/lon for a GPS is as fine as 1m, which should be sufficient for me.

Part of my problem is finding a device to use for employees to carry around.  The other is finding a device with a supported API (read: "free API") or other programming options.  I would like this to be manufacturer-independent.

I would love to do cross-platform development - iOS, Android, PC, web, etc.

Does anyone have experience with something like this, and what recommendations can you offer on where to start?  I know this is a little open ended but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This all does not work (tracking within a building).
GPS Signal is very poor or non existent within a building.

(Next time search here on Stackoverflow.  It has been asked some times.)

The only robust and working solution, are BlueTooth beacons.
Such small hardware pieces are mounted within the building.
Such beacons (search for iBeacon) just send out an id. 
The phone receives the id, and the approximate distance to it.
You have to administrate and know which id is at which level of the building.

Even when having good reception the GPS signal is not precise enough to determine the floor a person is location.

Some phones have a barometer, like the ipHone, this can track relative heigh changes, and may be used to determine level within a building. (Once calibrated before entering the buulding)